# c# can I add List<ChannelTreeItem> to treeview nodes?

Tags: c#, treeview

```
    private void show_info()
    {
        List<ChannelTreeItem> result = new List<ChannelTreeItem>();
        try
        {

            result = QueryUtils.GetChannelTree(TopQuery.GetChannelList().Values,TopQuery.GetClientList().Values);
            treeview1.nodes.add(result);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Retry later");
        }
    }
```

ErrorMsg : Cannot convert ChannelTreeItem to string

Can I add this List to treeview Nodes?

Comment: I am not familiar with "ChannelTreeItem" and i don't know whit does "GetChannelTree" return however i can tell you this, the "Add: method is generally used to add 1 item, when there is no appropriate loaded method that accept the given object type it falls back to the base and this is the error message you see. the "treeview1.Nodes,Add" accept as base a string. the supplied type of "ChannelTreeItem" is not supported by the method. You need to convert the "ChannelTreeItem" to a supported object type by the method: string/TreeNode etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you look at the definition for the mothod of Nodes.Add ( for TreeView) You will see you can only add an object of type  TreeNode or string:

So you need to make a conversion.  Either use ToString(), or create a TreeNode object and add that to your treeview

From you code:

```
List<ChannelTreeItem> result = new List<ChannelTreeItem>();
```

your result variable is of type list of ChannelTreeItems.  Its not clear to me what your want to put in your tree nodes. Do you want each node contain a list of ChannelTreeItems, or do you want one ChannelTreeItem per node?

To do the latter you will need to iterate through your list (for or foreach loop) and then add each item string to a new node which you can then add to your treeview.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx